# PHP - Create default default object from empty value

Tags: php, oop

This is my code: I want to update the User information and risk factors.

```
public function getUserById($id)
{
$user = $this->_xml->xpath('//user[@id="' . $id . '"]');
return $user[0]; 
}

public function updateUser($post)
{
$user = $this->_xml->xpath('//user[@id="' . $post['id'] . '"]');


$user[0]->name= $post["name"];
$user[0]->date_of_birth= $post["date_of_birth"];
$user[0]->sex= $post["sex"];
$user[0]->age= $post["age"];
$this->_xml->asXML($this->path);
}

public function updateFactors($post)
{

 $user = $this->_xml->xpath('//user[@id="' . $post['id'] . '"]');

//$user=new stdClass();
$user[0]->alcohol= $post["alcohol"];  // error here!
$user[0]->percentage= $post["percentage"];
$this->_xml->asXML($this->path);

} 
if ($param == "edit") {
$id = $arr[1];
$user = $process->getUserById($id);
include 'myuser2.php';


if ($param == "update") {
$post = $_POST;
$process->updateUser($post);
include 'mylistar.php';
$process->listUsers();
}


if ($param == "editfactors") {
$id = $arr[1];
$user = $process->getUserById($id);
include'factors.php';

}

if($param == "updatefactors"){
$post = $_POST;
$process->updateFactors($post);
include 'mylistar.php';
$process->listUsers();
}
```

So, the "update", "edit", the updateUser function is working... But the Factors part is not! The code is pretty much the same and I don´t know what I'm doing wrong... Seems logic to me.

> Error : Creating default object from empty value (in line 
>   $user[0]->alcohol= $post["alcohol"]; )

I've searched and tried `$user=new stdClass();` but it doesn't work:

```
Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Can you help? :/

Comment: So you want to create a default default?

Comment: what do you mean? i'm new too this, i'm trying to learn by examples/tutorials, really thought my code would work... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that Stdobject classes contain `functions` and not your conditional if statements? try splitting them up, so having methods inside your `class test { }` and if statements outside